# jQuery. Issue with checkbox check action

Tags: jquery

Why this script:

```
if ($('.applyrulles').is(':checked')) {                     
    $('.button').show(700);
} else {
    $('.button').hide();
}
```

doesn't work with `.button`?

```
<div>
    <input name="applyrulles" type="checkbox" class="applyrulles"/>
</div>  

<input type="submit" class="button" value="send"/>
```

Sript hides `.button`, but doesn't show it when `.applyrulles` is checked.

Comment: Have you tried using .toggle() instead?

Comment: @Blender On Colorbox (jQuery plugin) Ajax load. However, Tats_innit solved this issue.

Comment: @Blender `$('.column-right .button').colorbox({fixed:true, maxHeight:"100%"}, function(){ if... else... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mdFSb/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/mdFSb/1/

You need to capture an event like `click` or `change` and the use `$(this)` rest feel free to play around with code.

Hope this helps the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('.applyrulles').on('change', function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $('.button').show();

    } else {
        $('.button').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: @YNT No probs, Glad it helped! `:)`